Idiom request : a very small amount compared with what is needed
I'm looking for an English equivalent to the Hindi phrase:
Feeding cumin seeds to a camel.
Cumin seeds would not sate a camel's hunger. In fact, it is as good as giving nothing.
This phrase can be used in the following example:
"Suppose a project requires a million dollars and someone brings a tenner.
Is there an English equivalent for this saying?

a drop in the ocean/a drop in the bucket

Suppose a project requires a million dollars and someone brings a tenner. That tenner is a drop in the ocean (relatively speaking, so small as to make no difference). Sometimes a drop in a / the bucket.

Putting lipstick on a pig says you can dress things up, but it won't change their basic nature. Also, Pearls before swine, for lack of appreciation of your efforts.

Related on EL&U: An idiom meaning someone's doing something useless and has no result at the end.

A tenner isn't useless when crowdfunding so don't look a gift horse in the mouth.

Almost separately, please note that 'hunger' is not something to be 'fulfilled'. While 'ambition' or 'desire' might be 'fulfilled', 'hunger' needs to be 'assuaged' or 'satisfied', for instance.

Whatever language this comes from, how certain can you be that '… when too much is needed…' is exactly what was meant?
I'm suggesting 'more' or even simply 'much' might convey the real meaning but 'too much' is itself too much, and puts first the translation and then the whole question in doubt.

Idioms that suggest ineffectively small efforts:

Moving deckchairs on the Titanic
Trying to put out a fire with a thimble
Putting a band-aid on a bullet wound
A drop in the bucket
Scratching the surface

Other idioms that imply a pointless effort of any size:

Beating/Flogging a Dead Horse
Pissing in the Wind
Tilting at windmills
Pushing water uphill


Some of the idioms in your answer do match. It doesn't mean 'futile efforts" but "a very small amount compared with what is needed."

@JamesMathai You're right, about half of them do. I've broken them down into two sets.
